# generate 13 digit unique random number in c#

Tags: c#

Modify the follwing code to generate 13 digit unique random number in c#

```
public static string GenerateUniqueRandomNumbers()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        String r = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");
        if (r.Distinct().Count() == 1)
        {
            r = GenerateUniqueRandomNumbers();
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are having? Also note that this code doesn't generate a unique number either

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random 10 digit number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055489/how-to-generate-a-random-10-digit-number-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Very malformed question

IF your problem is that maxValue cannot have 13 digit, a quick workaround could be concatenate 2 strings

```
    String r = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");
    r += generator.Next(0, 10000000).ToString("D7");
```

Answer (score 0):

For 13 digits we need long variable but Random.Next method does not support long dataType it only support Integer data type. Hence , we have to do something tricky.

Check the below code to generate generate 13 digit number.

```
    Random generator = new Random();
    String r = generator.Next(0, 999999).ToString("D13");
```

Note: I have used ToString("D13") to get the 13 digits value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GenerateUniqueRandomNumbers()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        String r = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");
        r += generator.Next(0, 10000000).ToString("D7");
        if (r.Distinct().Count() == 1)
        {
            r = GenerateUniqueRandomNumbers();
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: That `if (r.Distinct().Count() == 1)` only blocks numbers that are using just 1 digit (like 11111). It doesn't know about previously generated 13-digit number strings

Answer (score 0):

```
    Random generator = new Random();
    string s = "380003562";
    s += generator.Next(0, 0000000).ToString("D"+(13-s.Length).ToString());
```

With this code, if you are using an existing number, you can quickly bring it to 13 digits or any digit number you want.